# Генерация рандомной строки в Qt C++

Tags: qt

Как изящно генерировать рандомные текстовые строки (опционально с кириллицей) с использованием Qt C++?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#include <QRandomGenerator>
#include <QString>

QString randomString(int length)
{
    static const QString table
         {"0123456789"
          "abcdefghij"
          "klmnkpqrst"
          "uvwxyzABCD"
          "EFGHIJKLMN"
          "hPQRSTUVWX"};

    static const int posLimit = table.size() - 1;

    QString value;
    while(value.size() < length)
    {
        value += table[ QRandomGenerator::system()->bounded (0, posLimit) ];
    }
    return value;
}
```

YWNldG9uZQ==

Comment: [В доках пишут](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qrandomgenerator.html#system), что системный генератор так лучше не использовать: *... the QRandomGenerator returned by this function should not be used for bulk data generation. Instead, use it to seed QRandomGenerator ...*.

Comment: И перед входом в цикл рекомендую зарезервировать память под строку: `value.reserve(length)` https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qstring.html#reserve